# Error: Unable to find a match in docker-dr-elephant build

Tags: docker

I'm testing dr-elephant :

> https://github.com/damienclaveau/docker-dr-elephant

But when i run :

```
docker build -t dr-elephant:2.0.6 .
```

I'm getting

```
Complete!
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:19 ago on Thu Oct 24 07:51:21 2019.
No match for argument: krb5-auth-dialog
No match for argument: pam_krb5
Error: Unable to find a match
The command '/bin/sh -c yum install -y wget git unzip zip which  && yum install -y krb5-server krb5-libs krb5-workstation  && yum install -y krb5-auth-dialog pam_krb5  && yum install -y openssh-server openssh-clients  && yum clean all' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Any idea on how to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: krb5-auth-dialog is no longer available in all RHEL directives up from version 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is right there: `yum` couldn't install packages named `pam_krb5` and `krb5-auth-dialog`

You can easily test this by running the `centos` image and try to install those packages:

```
[root@228fcb9e4c19 /]# yum install -y krb5-auth-dialog pam_krb5
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
CentOS-8 - AppStream                                                                                                                                                                                                                            1.1 MB/s | 6.0 MB     00:05
CentOS-8 - Base                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 2.0 MB/s | 7.9 MB     00:03
CentOS-8 - Extras                                                                                                                                                                                                                               634  B/s | 2.1 kB     00:03
No match for argument: krb5-auth-dialog
No match for argument: pam_krb5
Error: Unable to find a match
```

About how to fix this... you could try to remove that line (9 in the Dockerfile), but how do you know whether those packages were necessary by the app or not? So your best bet is to just contact the owner and tell him that his Dockerfile no longer works (it's 2 years old).

Usually this problem arises because the base image doesn't have a fixed version. You can check it's using `FROM centos:latest`, but today's centos is not the same as the centos of two years ago. You could also just try to edit the tag of the base image and use an older centos version, it might or might not work.